# "ERROR - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'axes'" when trying to read pickle file from s3 bytes object

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, pickle, series

I'm running the following code within an Apache airflow environment to get a pickle file from s3 and read it into memory. As soon as I try to read/print the file contents, I get the error:

`ERROR - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'axes'`

---

CODE

```py
import boto3
import pickle


# [...Omitted code...]  

s3_session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=secret_key
)

s3 = s3_session.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object(bucket_name, KEY)
pickle_contents = obj.get()['Body'].read()
body = pickle.loads(pickle_contents)

print(body)

# ^-- This is where the error happens, as soon as I try to read it.
```

This code actually seems to work fine on a separate Jupyter notebook instance, which leads to me guess at a version incompatibility issue? The pickle file looks like the dictionary below, thanks to my Jupyter notebook letting me `print(body)`:

PICKLE FILE BODY:

```
{75: 
  'recommendation_diversity_metrics': 
    {'largest_subcategory_group_proportion': 
      {'mean': 0.3369472,
       'sd': 0.1741708739837092,
       'min': 0.05333333333333334,
       'max': 1.0},
     'catalogue_entropy': 3.4412171579585533,
     'subcategory_overweight_frequency': 
        School & Office Supplies    0.73020
        Pants                       0.70656
        Bedding                     0.64138
        Sweaters                    0.62616
        Tops                        0.57044
                                     ...   
        Cleanup & Odor Control      0.00144
        UNKNOWN                     0.00036
        Body Piercings              0.00034
        Misc Books                  0.00012
        Home Books                  0.00012
        Length: 94, dtype: float64},
  'recommendation_novelty_metrics': {
    'previously_interacted': {'mean': 0.052456533333333326,
      'sd': 0.06291214458333363,
      'min': 0.0,
      'max': 0.6},
    'new_product_frequency': {'mean': 0.016672799999999998,
      'sd': 0.01423356021834222,
      'min': 0.0,
      'max': 0.12}
      }}
```

***I think the error is happening because I have a pandas Series object within the dictionary (see `subcategory_overweight_frequency` in the dictionary above).*** Because as long as I only read in all the dictionary elements besides that specific one, then the interpreter lets my code run fine. Am I missing a dependency for this that I don't know about?

---

FULL TRACEBACK

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 655, in __repr__
    show_dimensions=show_dimensions,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 774, in to_string
    line_width=line_width,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 484, in __init__
    self.max_rows_displayed = min(max_rows or len(self.frame), len(self.frame))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 996, in __len__
    return len(self.index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5175, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
  File "pandas/_libs/properties.pyx", line 63, in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__get__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'axes'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have pickled the DataFrame with a later version of Pandas and might be trying to read the pickle file with an earlier version.

Please verify the version you used to pickle the DataFrame with and which Pandas version you are using with Airflow.

Comment: This is exactly right. Unfortunately, Airflow (Astronomer) doesn't allow specifying whatever version of pandas you want in the requirements.txt file, so I either need to upgrade Airflow versions or have the source data for that element changed to standard python lists.

Comment: Happy that you found the culprit. So it's not installing apache-airflow from the `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Astronomer has there own system level python and OS packages that are installed upon container startup, but the airflow runtime modules are specified in a requirements.txt file, however, it gives me an error when I try to install a different version of pandas in the requirements.txt. Potentially I could try installing the pandas version I need at the user level (from the Dockerfile), but I will not do that for now, since I have implemented a workaround (changed the source data to standard python lists)